How to correctly use condition_variable and time_wait/timed_join in threads?
I'm experiencing a wierd behaviour with thread. I isolated the problem in this simple example:
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#define SLEEP_DURATION 1000

static boost::thread m_powerThread;
static boost::condition_variable m_exitThreadCond;
static boost::mutex m_exitThreadMutex;

void ThreadFunc()
{
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock( m_exitThreadMutex );
    std::cout << "Thread starts waiting" << std::endl;
    while ( !m_exitThreadCond.timed_wait( lock, boost::posix_time::milliseconds( SLEEP_DURATION ) ) )
    {
        // timed-out: m_exitThreadCond was not notified
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }
    // m_exitThreadCond was notified, let's exit
    std::cout << "Exiting thread" << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    m_powerThread = boost::thread( boost::bind<void>(&ThreadFunc) );

    // make sure thread started for good
    boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 500 ) );

    m_exitThreadMutex.lock();
    m_exitThreadCond.notify_all();
    m_exitThreadMutex.unlock();

    /* Then wait for the thread to exit. */
    if ( m_powerThread.timed_join( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 2*SLEEP_DURATION ) ) )
    {
        std::cout << "OK, joined thread" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "KO, failed to joined thread" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

It creates a thread tht will check a condition, if not notified within 1s, it will print "Hello", if condition is notified, thread exits. The main program set's the condition and calls timed_join.
When I run the program, it works fine, output is:
Thread starts waiting
Exiting thread
OK, joined thread

But When I add some breakpoints, it fails. I add a breakpoint to boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::milliseconds( 500 ) ); and run the debugger (Visual Studio).
It stops at my breakpoint, I step to next instruction, app sleeps for 500ms and I see "Thread starts waiting" in the console, then I step to the notify_all line and later timed_join, but I see timed_join returns false and console outputs:
Hello
Hello
KO, failed to joined threadHello

Hello

Am I using the condition/mutex badly? I undertsand stopping on breakpoints impacts application timing and thread but it should not make it fail in this specific case.
Notes:

If I hit "continue" after the app stopped on breakpoint, the test works fine, timed_join succeeds
I'm not sure main has to lock/unlock m_exitThreadMutex. Commenting the lines has no impact, timed_join when running the app step by step


Side note : You don't have to use boost, condition_variable is part of the C++ standard libary. Or did you forget to mention that you're still on C++98? (same for boost::bind, you can use C++'s lambda expressions)

I have the problem in legacy code that was written a long time ago with boost, and never migrated to use std.

For std::condition_variable (and I suspect boost's one too), ALWAYS wait with a predicate to avoid spurious wakeups creating issues. (Read : Be Aware of the Traps of Condition Variables)

If you have unit tests, and need to fix a bug... consider refactoring now :)

@PepijnKramer: Do you mean I must add a static std::atomic_bool m_continueThread = true;, set it to false before calling notify_all and modify thread if statement to check m_continueThread in addition to timed_wait?

Probably a bool is fine (since you will be updating and reading from it from the same lock as used in the condition variable). But yes. Nice bonus, you can now also exit before the 500ms have finished (so you need to check the return of the wait).

Here is what I mean in code, I didn't use boost (because I am not fully sure it works the same way as the std implementation, some names of functions are already a bit different).
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

//#define SLEEP_DURATION 1000 <-- do NOT use #define

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// NO GLOBALS, wrap in a class

class PowerFunction final
{
public:
    ~PowerFunction()
    {
        m_thread.join();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        m_thread = std::thread{ [&] { MainLoop(); } };
        WaitForThreadState(ThreadState::Running); // make sure thread started for good
    }

    void Stop()
    {
        SetThreadState(ThreadState::Stopping);
        WaitForThreadState(ThreadState::Stopped);
    }

private:
    // Your thread can be in various states, which will be used
    // in condition variable waits.
    // this will also ensure your startup can be synchronized (see Start)
    enum class ThreadState
    {
        Starting,
        Running,
        Stopping,
        Stopped
    };

    static constexpr std::chrono::steady_clock::duration LoopTime = 1s;

    void MainLoop()
    {
        SetThreadState(ThreadState::Running);
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Hello\n";
        } while (!WaitForThreadState(ThreadState::Stopping, LoopTime));
        std::cout << "Exiting thread\n";
        SetThreadState(ThreadState::Stopped);
    }

    void SetThreadState(const ThreadState state)
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock lock{ m_mtx };
            m_state = state;
        }
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void WaitForThreadState(const ThreadState state)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{ m_mtx };
        m_cv.wait(lock, [&] { return m_state == state; }); // <-- Wait with predicate
    }

    bool WaitForThreadState(const ThreadState state, const std::chrono::steady_clock::duration& duration)
    {
        std::unique_lock lock{ m_mtx };
        return m_cv.wait_for(lock, duration, [&] { return m_state == state; }); // <-- Wait with predicate AND timeout
    }

    std::thread m_thread;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    ThreadState m_state{ ThreadState::Starting };
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    PowerFunction powerFunction;
    powerFunction.Start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s); // let mainloop do its thing for a while

    powerFunction.Stop();
}


You're welcome, I hope you can translate this to your application :)
